# Difference between Class and Class.type in Scala

Tags: scala, types

The following snippet explain my confusion:

```
scala> case class fellow[A, B](name:A, age:B)
class fellow

scala> :t -v fellow
// Type signature
fellow.type

// Internal Type structure
TypeRef(
  pre = ThisType(class $iw)
  TypeSymbol(class fellow extends Serializable)
)

scala> :kind -v fellow.type
fellow.type's kind is A
*
This is a proper type.

scala> :kind -v fellow
fellow's kind is F[A1,A2]
* -> * -> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.
```

Why fellow.type is different than fellow (as a type)
I don't get why those two type are different, and why :t -v returns fellow.type ?

Write after this little experiment i checked against List and saw that it was the same

```
scala> :kind -v List
List's kind is F[+A]
* -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.

scala> :kind -v List.type
scala.collection.immutable.List.type's kind is A
*
This is a proper type.
```

So what is the `.type` about exaxctly ? Where does it come from ? how does it differ from the other ... Trait Name, Class name

Comment: That is the type of the companion object of the class. For example the type of **Nil** is `Nil.type` - Note that also, the `.type` syntax can be used to access the singleton type of a value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`foo.type` for any `foo` denotes the [*singleton type*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#singleton-types) of `foo`, i.e. the type which has `foo` as its only instance. (Or, more precisely, for instances of `AnyRef`, the type which has only `foo` and `null` as its instances.) Please note that in the syntactic construction `foo.type` the `foo` part is a *value* (more precisely, a *path* to a value), whereas `foo.type` is a *type*.

Also, remember that [a `case class` automatically generates a *companion module*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes) of the same name, i.e. whenever you write

```scala
case class foo
```

there is also an implicit

```scala
object foo
```

So what is happening here, is that when you *think* you are asking for the type of the *class* `foo`, you are *actually* asking about the type of the [*singleton object*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#object-definitions) `foo`. And the type of the singleton object `foo` is the singleton type `foo.type`, by definition.

Answer (score 4):

I'll just add that besides `:t` in REPL you can use `typeOf` in ordinary Scala code

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

typeOf[fellow[_, _]].typeSymbol // class fellow
typeOf[fellow.type].typeSymbol // object fellow
```

i.e. a class and its companion object.

For values you can also do

```
def getType[A: TypeTag](a: A): Type = typeOf[A]

getType(fellow("a", 1)).typeSymbol // class fellow
getType(fellow).typeSymbol // object fellow
```

Comment: In fact from the start i should have not done `:t fellow`, cause actually fellow is already a type. It worked because i had a case class. So from the start it should have been. `:k fellow` .  This being said i understand all the above point. I will have a look at typeTag a little

Comment: @MaatDeamon For values you can also use `getType`. See update.